# How can I use annotation @IntRange for Kotlin extension function for Integer

Tags: kotlin, annotations, extension-function

below is my Kotlin extension function :

```
infix fun Int.send(data: String) {
    MsgSendUtils.sendStringMsg(
        this,
        data
    )
}
```

called  like  this  :

```
 8401 send "hi"
```

and my requirement is :
**the  caller  must  greater than  8400 .**

How can i achieve that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

In theory, you can use the syntax `@receiver:IntRange(from = 8400)` to apply an annotation to the receiver of a function:

```kotlin
infix fun @receiver:IntRange(from = 8400) Int.send(data: String) {
    MsgSendUtils.sendStringMsg(this, data)
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to trigger the Android Lint error as you would expect. This is probably a missing feature in the linter itself when inspecting Kotlin code.

A workaround would be to declare the function differently (using this value as parameter instead of receiver):

```kotlin
fun send(@IntRange(from = 8400) id: Int, data: String) {
    MsgSendUtils.sendStringMsg(id, data)
}
// or
fun String.sendTo(@IntRange(from = 8400) id: Int) {
    MsgSendUtils.sendStringMsg(id, this)
}
```

Otherwise the best you could do in pure Kotlin would be to check the value at runtime:

```kotlin
infix fun Int.send(data: String) {
    require(this >= 8400) { "This value must be greater than 8400" }
    MsgSendUtils.sendStringMsg(this, data)
}
```

Note that, depending on what this value represents, I would advise using a more specific type instead of `Int`. For example, if your `Int` represents an ID, maybe you should instead declare a `value class` wrapping this integer. You can then enforce the constraints at construction time (still at runtime, but it's less error-prone).

This approach would also avoid polluting auto-completion on all integers, which can be pretty annoying on a big project given how specific this function is.